# AngularJS unknown provider $$cookieReaderProvider

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de usar las **ngCookies** de AngularJS, pero al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto me aparece el siguiente error:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader
```

Este es un ejemplo de mi código

```
 var ole_no_ldap = angular.module('ole_no_ldap', ['ngRoute', 'localization', 'SharedServices','pascalprecht.translate','ngCookies']);


angular.module('ole_no_ldap').controller('CreatePasswordController', function($scope, $http, $translate,$cookies) {
         $cookies.put('language', 'spanish');
}
```

Comment: que version de angular estas usando ? que version de la libreria de cookies usas ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini La version de angular que uso es la 1.2 y la version de la librería de las cookies es la 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Te consulte por la version de angular que usas porque he notado que consultas sobre el mismo tema

[AngularJS unknown provider cookieReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885568/angularjs-unknown-provider-cookiereader)

[AngularJS: Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859779/angularjs-unknown-provider-cookiereaderprovider-cookiereader-cookie)

plantean actualizar la version de angular, para resolverlo